bids management solution
I'm tasked with managing technical and financial bids for computer and IT-related staff.
I'm seeking a more efficient solution than Excel or Google Sheets to streamline my bidding process. Is there a suitable SaaS or offline tool that can help me organize tender documents, deadlines, third-party offers, and other critical bidding elements?

You should be more specific about your needs/expectations.

@BasilBourque I am the bidder, just need something to organize myself and keep track of my bids, please, could you tell me what other details i could provide to you?
